# NSUserDefaults initWithSuiteName data nil on iWatch

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

I am trying to transfer data from my main device to my iwatch and that data is nil. I have tried to retrieve the data on the main device and that works. Please note that I did add the app groups.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're using watch os 2 then it doesn't have access to shared defaults/files in app groups

Comment: You also shouldn't store passwords in user defaults, use keychain for that

Comment: I am using watch os 2. Thank you